# How to access a controller variable from the view

Tags: c#, html, variables, asp.net-mvc-4

I started experimenting with C# and HTML5 today. I thought this question would be easy to find an answer to, but I couldn't find it on Google or here. I created a MVC4 default template.
I have an ascx file, which is my form view. It's currently like this

```
<hgroup class="title">
<h1>Log in.</h1>
<h2>Enter username and password</h2>
```

But instead of a hardcoded "Log in." I want to put a localization String there from another class called HomeController.cs

So I thought I'd do it like this. (Which I'm used to doing because so far I only know Java)

```
<hgroup class="title">
<h1><script>HomeController.strings.voerIn</script></h1>
<h2>Enter username and password</h2>
</hgroup>
```

However, that just shows the variable name as text instead of the variable value.
I tried wrapping those variables in script> or code> but that doesn't seem to help.

EDIT: ANSWER

Okay, so i finally got it to work.
I had to instantiate HomeController, and instead of <% %> displaying the string I had to use <%= %>

so this is what my code looks like now, and it works!!

```
<% MvcApplication2.Controllers.HomeController hc=new MvcApplication2.Controllers.HomeController();%>
  <h2><%=hc.aha%></h2>
```

Comment: Since you're using MVC4, I'd use razor instead of the webforms viewengine. It's much less ugly.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To put code in your page, you must use <% %>.

Comment: You're probably right, but I don't know what is Rzor, and this is not mentioned in his question.

Comment: i dont know what razor is either, i'm really noob at this :P i will give this option a go.

Comment: i cannot acces my variables this way, do i have to import the namespace or something?

Comment: if you right click on the variable with the red squiggly underline, do you get a "Resolve" option?

Comment: Mmmh I don't think so.. I'm not very familiar with it. Do you have a .aspx.cs page ?

Comment: global.asax.cs ? You should have a .aspx.cs associated to your .aspx page, like Default.aspx.cs or something like it.

Comment: oh yea, it's still the standard files for the project, but index.aspx is probably the file you mean? edit: stupid comment by me? lol

Comment: there is no aspx.cs file in the project

Comment: Nop, in my project it's called default.aspx but nevermind ! in index.aspx.cs you should have `protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)`, can't you use it to display your string, like `MyLabel.Text = MyString;` ?

Comment: Crap this is very weird... I'm sorry I don't know how to do then... :/

Comment: it's probably because i use the MVC4 template that i dont have that file, i do think its strange that i cant just call a variable from another class....

Comment: This might be the reason.. 'Cause I can call variables with "ASP.NET Web Application", but I didn't try with MVC.

Comment: i can instantiate homecontroller by doing  
<% MvcApplication2.Controllers.HomeController hc=new MvcApplication2.Controllers.HomeController();%>

but then when i call variable it tells me i can only increment decrement etc.  (<h2><%hc.aha%></h2>)

Comment: I'm afraid I don't know how to do then... I'm sorry about that. :/

Comment: i got it!! gimme a sec to formulate the anwser to my own question :P without ur help i wouldn't have gotten there so thx!

Comment: oow i cant anwser myself until 7 hours from now

Comment: Glad you got the answer to your problem ! Happy coding !